# Jumping to desired screens on pressing an item in Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am writing a code in flutter and the screen with the bottom navigation bar looks like this.
[image: Home Screen]

What I want is that whenever I press the home button from the bottom navigation bar it should jump to the home screen, similarly for other screens like clicking the caregiver icon I want to move to Caregiver Screen and so on for others. I cannot figure this out by using BottomNaviagtionBar. Please help me out.

Code for Home Screen that contains my bottom navigation bar:

```
import 'package:epicare/HistoryScreen.dart';
import 'package:epicare/ProfileScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_switch/flutter_switch.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'CaregiverScreen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: new Drawer(),
body: Column(),
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 70,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
          ],
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),

          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedFontSize: 10,
            selectedFontSize: 10,
            selectedLabelStyle: optionStyle,
            currentIndex: _currentIndex,
            selectedItemColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
            unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
            onTap: onTabTapped,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ImageIcon(
                  AssetImage('assets/images/home.png'),
                  color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                ),
                title: new Text(
                  'Home',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ImageIcon(
                  AssetImage(
                    'assets/images/caregiver.png',
                  ),
                  color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                ),
                title: new Text(
                  'Caregiver',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ImageIcon(
                  AssetImage('assets/images/history.png'),
                  color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'History',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ImageIcon(
                  AssetImage('assets/images/profile.png'),
                  color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'Profile',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

P.S: I am still learning flutter
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

in your state class, put this at the beginning:

```
int _currentIndex = 0;
```

At the beginning of you build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final _widgetOptions = [
  Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [ Stack( 
    children: [ Container( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, 
    horizontal: 47),
  CaregiverScreen(),
  HistoryScreen(),
  ProfileScreen()
];
```

This should be your body:

```
body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_currentIndex),
```

Comment: I have other containers, columns for other widgets inside "body:", where should I place it -> _widgetOptions.elementAt(_currentIndex), then?

Comment: body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 47),

Something like this is written inside my body

Comment: all the 4 pages should be in _widgetOptions at the beginning of the build. Replace firstPage() with the Widget you want to use for the first page, etc...

Comment: Yeah i got that but what i am saying is that i am stuck at this part :
`body:_widgetOptions.elementAt(_currentIndex),
      Column(),`
I have a column and other widgets inside my body, so when i write "_widgetOptions.elementAt(_currentIndex)," before Column, it gives me an error. How should I cater to that problem?

Comment: The Column() is not your first page? You should only write  body:_widgetOptions.elementAt(_currentIndex). You should not put the Column there anymore

Comment: yes, it is my first page, and code for the other widgets is also written in the same dart file and the code for the bottom navigation bar is also written in the same file i.e HomeScreen.dart file

Comment: How do you normally call the other pages?

Comment: I use onPressed for jumping to other pages whenever andor wherever required.

Comment: I get it, I'll shift my bottom navigation bar to another dart file and will call the other screens from the file then. 
Thanks a bunch for ur help :)

Comment: The Bottom navigation can actually stay the same file. When I use it, I let it in the same file, but the pages are in other files and I just call them in the _widgetOptions.
I hope that your code works now.

Comment: Cool. I am very happy for you. :-)