# Flutter: How to navigate to second navigation screen (bottom navigation) using only buttons in Home screen?

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, flutter-routes

In my project, I used indexing for my BottomNavigationBar items. It controlled all the three main screen I have (Home, Ticketing, & Profile). Literally, I just used the bottom navigation buttons to navigate between the screens. As alternative way, I wanted to custom a button which located in Home screen. So that when it tapped, it will navigate to the Ticketing (2nd screen).

I tried to use `Navigator.pushNamed(context, screenName);`, but it will stack above all the screens and not showing the BottomNavigationBar.

Comment: Read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956973/jumping-to-desired-screens-on-pressing-an-item-in-bottom-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
  
void main() => runApp(MyApp());  
  
/// This Widget is the main application widget.  
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return MaterialApp(  
      home: MyNavigationBar (),  
    );  
  }  
}  
  
class MyNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {  
  MyNavigationBar ({Key key}) : super(key: key);  
  
  @override  
  _MyNavigationBarState createState() => _MyNavigationBarState();  
}  
  
class _MyNavigationBarState extends State<MyNavigationBar > {  
  int _selectedIndex = 0;  
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[  
    Text('Home Page', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),  
    Text('Search Page', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),  
    Text('Profile Page', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),  
  ];  
  
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {  
    setState(() {  
      _selectedIndex = index;  
    });  
  }  
  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return Scaffold(  
      appBar: AppBar(  
        title: const Text('Flutter BottomNavigationBar Example'),  
          backgroundColor: Colors.green  
      ),  
      body: Center(  
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),  
      ),  
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(  
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[  
          BottomNavigationBarItem(  
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),  
            title: Text('Home'),  
            backgroundColor: Colors.green  
          ),  
          BottomNavigationBarItem(  
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),  
            title: Text('Search'),  
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow  
          ),  
          BottomNavigationBarItem(  
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),  
            title: Text('Profile'),  
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,  
          ),  
        ],  
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,  
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,  
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,  
        iconSize: 40,  
        onTap: _onItemTapped,  
        elevation: 5  
      ),  
    );  
  }  
}
```

in _onItemTapped(int index)  method just change your view index like, better to you make one controller class you you can achive any othe widget or class.

```
void _onItemTapped() {  
        setState(() {  
          _selectedIndex = 1;  
        });  
      }
```